How to Use Both Internet and IPTV on Android TV via the Same Ethernet Connection?
I'm facing a challenge with my Android TV setup, and I’m hoping someone can help me out.
Here’s the situation:
My Android TV is connected to my ISP via an Ethernet cable to LAN Port 2 on the ONU (Optical Network Unit).
My ISP provides two VLAN profiles:

VLAN 135 for internet.
VLAN 1900 for IPTV (supports IGMP).

The ONU only allows binding one VLAN profile per LAN port.

If I bind VLAN 1900, I can watch IPTV, but I lose internet access on
the TV (no OTT apps work).
If I bind VLAN 135, I have internet access but no IPTV service.

Additional details:

My ISP is developing its own IPTV app that can be installed directly
on Android TVs, eliminating the need for a separate set-top box.
I considered using Wi-Fi for internet access while keeping the
Ethernet cable for IPTV, but the TV automatically disables Wi-Fi when
it detects an Ethernet connection.

My Questions:

Is there a way to enable both internet and IPTV on my Android TV
using the same Ethernet connection?
If not, is there a workaround to make the TV use Wi-Fi for internet
while keeping the Ethernet connection active for IPTV?
Are there any specific networking solutions (like VLAN management
devices or switch configurations) that can help resolve this?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!


Sorry, home networking, consumer-grade hardware and host configurations/issues are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [su].
